# Given a number, how to find the length of its binary representation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I think of $\text{log}_2$. But it does not work. For $8 = 2^3$, but the binary representation of 8 is $1000$. The length of it is 4. Any suggestion or help? Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: continue thinking of $\log_2$, but don't give up on it at the first sign of failure.  Just needs a tiny adjustment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The length of $x$ is $\lfloor{(\log_2(x))}\rfloor+1$.

Comment: How to prove it?

Comment: @funnydman It can be proven easily by introducing $n$ such that $2^n\leq x<2^{n+1}$ and show the length and the expression in the answer are both $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

For numbers $\leq64$ the length of $x$ is $\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + 1$. After $64$ and $x\equiv 1\;\text{mod}\; 2$, the length is $\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + $.

So the answer is:

```
if(x > 64 && x % 2 != 0){
    length = floor(log2(x)) + 2
}else{
    length = floor(log2(x)) + 1
}
```

Edit:

Sorry this is for get the firs number of the binary to zero after 64, the answer is log2(x) + 1