# Floor operation and ceiling operator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

From [Given a number, how to find the length of its binary representation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508902/given-a-number-how-to-find-the-length-of-its-binary-representation/1508909#1508909)

I think of a question:
Given an decimal number, is floor[n] + 1 = ceiling[n]?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=N+\alpha$, where $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\lt\alpha\lt1$.

Then $\lfloor n \rfloor = N$ and $\lceil n \rceil = N+1$.

If we allow $\alpha=0$ then we have the inequality $\lfloor n \rfloor + 1 \ge \lceil n \rceil$, with inequality iff $\alpha=0$.