# Number of bits in 0

Tags: information-theory, binary

I have found a few sources which have said that the number of bits in a binary number is equal to

$floor(log_2(n))+1$.

But this doesn't seem to work for binary values less than 1.  I would expect the value 0 to have zero bits.  But plugging in 0 for n is not in the domain of the function.  Stranger results are given by plugging in values like 0.2 which give -2 bits.  This doesn't sound right.  So I created this equation:

$ceil(log_2(n+1))$.

It has the same output as the previous function for all $n>=1$.  It even says 0 is 0 bits, and 0.2 is 1 bit, as I would expect.

Why do people seem to like the first function more?  Can someone explain why the number of bits in 0 is undefined in terms of Shannon information?

EDIT:

Here are a the sources I drew from:

https://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/

[Given a number, how to find the length of its binary representation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508902/given-a-number-how-to-find-the-length-of-its-binary-representation)

MathWorld states the first equation is equal to the second, but ignores values less than 1.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BitLength.html

EDIT 2:

I'm looking for a strict mathematical explanation for the number of bits in 0 in terms of information theory.  The two equations above give different answers, so which is correct and why?  To clarify, I don't mean the physical length of '0' or the length of the string that represents '0', but the value zero itself.

According to Mathematica,

> "BitLength[n] gives the number of binary bits necessary to represent the integer n"

and executing this command,

```
BitLength[0] -> 0
```

but even the Mathematica documentation and MathWorld fail to give a reason for this.

Comment: *NB:* $0$ has precisely **one** bit.

Comment: Also, please would you link to the sources?

Comment: @Shaun Neither equation indicates that 0 has one bit.  Zero can not have a positive number of bits because zero is an absence of possible states.  If there are no possible states, then no information can be encoded in them.  For example, a memory bank that contains a '0' is the same as no memory bank at all.  And thus, it holds zero bits of information.

Comment: @DanielWilliams "a memory bank that contains a '0' is the same as no memory bank at all." That seems very false to me: it contains a $0$, after all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I say this because a 0 is the same as a disconnected wire.

Comment: No, $0$ is a state. There is a difference between $\{0\}$ and $\emptyset=\{\}$.

Comment: Maybe there's a different convention in information theory than what I'm used to though . . .

Comment: I believe it is different in information theory.  Yes, 0 is a state.  But if '0' is the only possible state, then no information can be encoded in that state.  This is because the Shannon entropy of a single state is $-1*log_2(1)=0$.  So zero bits are encoded in a single possible state.  The equation I just used however, seems to contradict the first equation in my post.

Comment: I think there might be a disconnect about what "number of bits" means here. I think the sources are referring to the length of the binary sequence representing the number - certainly this is the case in [this source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508902/given-a-number-how-to-find-the-length-of-its-binary-representation) you mentioned - so that e.g. ten has four bits since ten is represented by the string "$1010$." Since zero is represented by "$0$" rather than by the empty string, zero has one bit; meanwhile, non-natural numbers like $0.2$ aren't being talked about here.

Comment: *I say this because a 0 is the same as a disconnected wire.* Well, blind people do not see black; rather, they do not see.

Answer (score 2):

The formulas you quote are for the number of bits in the binary expression of a positive integer.  As you say, the first is undefined for $0$ and the second gives $0$ bits.  I would say both are wrong for $0$ because it takes one binary digit (note I did not say bit) to express $0$, but those formulas are intended only for positive integers.  They agree for all of those.

This is different from the number of bits for $0$ in information theory.  In information theory you need to consider the number of possibilities.  If you have $256$ equally probable values for a quantity, any one of them is $8$ bits, whether it is $0$ or $234$.